# Navigation inside bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to navigate in a bootstrap modal.Suppose that I open a modal and I have a button in this modal that navigate me to another page that opens in this modal.How I should implement this Scenario in bootstrap modal.Can I use angular routing or I should try showing remote page in modal?I prefer to use a method that doesn't need to changing the scope.

Comment: "I prefer to use a method that doesn't need to changing the scope." -- Then you probably don't want to use routing.  The solution really depends on what you want to do inside the modal.  Post some more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Just create multiple pages (divs) inside your modal. Then show or hide these pages as necessary.

for example, you can create an isSet() function in your ModalController and do something like

```
<div ng-show="isSet(1)">Page 1<div>
<div ng-show="isSet(2)">Page 2<div>
```